# Python CLI tool is not added to path after installation with pip

Tags: python, windows, macos, pip, python-packaging

I have developed a small CLI tool and it works fine for Linux users. However, Mac and sometimes Windows users struggle with the installation using pip.

They usually find the package inside their installed global packages, but somehow their shell is not auto discovering the commands from the `.toml`

I am unsure if the mistake is with my `.toml` file. Maybe one of you can check?

Also, how would I go and set up a .zshrc path so it includes Python installed cli packages/commands into the path?

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "wd-cli"
version = "0.0.8"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
   "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
   "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
dependencies = [
"charset-normalizer==2.1.0",
"click==8.1.3",
"prompt-toolkit==1.0.14",
"pyfiglet==0.8.post1",
"Pygments==2.12.0",
"PyInquirer==1.0.3",
"requests==2.28.1",
"xdg==5.1.1",
"python-dotenv==0.20.0",
"click-aliases==1.0.1"
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
test = [
    "pytest==6.2.5",
    "pytest-cov==3.0.0",
]


[tool.setuptools.packages]
find = {}

[project.scripts]
wd-cli="src.main:main"
wd="src.main:main"
```

The project set up:

[image]

The root level main.py is not used. I struggled with imports and getting it to work hence I put everything into an `src` folder, which somehow solved my issues for linux.

main.py (not used as far as I know)

```py
from src import main   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

src/main.py (actually used for cli)

```py
def main():
    load_dotenv(f"{os.getcwd()}/.env") 
    cli()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Seeing your project's directory structure would be helpful. Without it we can not guess what your top-level import modules and/or packages are, as well as the sub-packages. This is important to know how to write your entry points in the `[project.scripts]` table. Typically there should not be any `src` in there if your project follows the `src` layout correctly (which I doubt).

Comment: @sinoroc I added the additional information you requested. YOu are correct the src folder was added because I somehow had issues that imports stopped working after I build it. But I am not sure if this is the issue? As I said it works just fine for me on Linux. Other OS usually work as well just for some they will get `wd command not found`

Answer (score 0):

The project's directory structure does not follow a correct `src`-layout.

Look at the [*setuptools* doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout), or this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Pay close attention to the directory structure.

The project should not have `src/main.py` and `src/__init__.py` files, but `src/wd_cli/main.py` and `src/wd_cli/__init__.py` instead. The imports should look like this: `from wd_cli import main`. The `[project.scripts]` entry points should look like this: `wd-cli="wd_cli.main:main"`.